# Unable to transfer data between two ESP8266

Tags: sockets, networking, arduino, esp8266

I am trying to connect two **esp 8266** (**Wi-fi**) module with each other one as **hotspot (server)**  using Wifi of **ESP12 E** **module 8266** and other is (client).I am Using **Arduino IDE** for programming

my server starts properly and client is connected to server but when I send data  from client to server I got nothing. I google about data transfer between client and server, but nothing is there for client data transfer using Arduino coding.

Here is My code in **Arduino**

**server side code**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

WiFiServer server(80);        //Initialize the server on Port 80

void setup() 
{

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);                              // ESP8266-12E is an AccessPoint 
  WiFi.softAP("11111111", "12345678");            // Provide the (SSID, password)  
  server.begin();                                // Start the Server
  Serial.begin(115200);                         //Start communication between the ESP8266-12E and the monitor window
  IPAddress HTTPS_ServerIP= WiFi.softAPIP();   // Obtain the IP of the Server 
  Serial.print("Server IP is: ");             // Print the IP to the monitor window 
  Serial.println(HTTPS_ServerIP);

}

void loop()
{
   WiFiClient client = server.available();
   if (!client)
    { 
       return; 
    } 
   //Looking under the hood 
   Serial.println("Somebody has connected :)"); 
}
```

**client side code**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>


const char *ssid = "11111111";
const char *password = "12345678";
const char *host = "192.168.4.2";
const int httpPort = 80;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid); 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


void loop()
{
  delay(8000);
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);
  WiFiClient client;
  client.connect(host,httpPort);
  if (!client.connect(host,httpPort))
  {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }
  else
   client.print("connected");
}
```

can any one suggest me how to transfer data from client to server

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino ESP8266 class `WiFiClient` inherits from `Stream`, so, all stream functions are available to you. You can find documentation for that class [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Stream).

You could use `readBytes`, `readString`, or just plain `read` to do what you want.

Additionally, if you do plan to use HTTP, you may be interested in using the libraries `ESP8266WebServer` and `ESP8266HTTPClient` which come with your ESP8266 Arduino environment and implement a lot of this low level code you are attempting to write. You can find examples for the server [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples), and the client [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples)

Comment: i am trying libraries ESP8266WebServer and ESP8266HTTPClient but data is not transfer to server.. basically at client esp 8266 module  i connect temperature sensor if give  hotspot to client esp module  through my mobile then i got the temperature value on webpage on ip which i get after connection.. but when i do same thing using hotspot of ESP 8266  module then i can't get temperature value on IP so please help me where i am wrong.

Comment: Can you add `Serial.setDebugOutput(true)` to both your client and server code, and post the output here? Additionally, can you update your post with the new code?